# Prove that vector tangent to a curve always maintains the same angle, so the ratio between curvature and torsion is constant

Tags: vector-spaces, curves, curvature

I have a 3D curve parametrized by the arc length, $r(s)$, which I compute the curvature $\kappa$ and de torsion $\tau$ as:
\begin{equation}
    \kappa(s) = ||\frac{dT}{ds}|| = ||r''(s)||\\
    \tau (s) = \frac{(r'(s) \times r''(s)) \cdot r'''(s)}{\kappa(s)^2} = \frac{(r'(s) \times r''(s)) \cdot r'''(s)}{||r''(s)||^2}
\end{equation}

Using the Lancret theorem I can prove that the curve is a helix, by proving that the relation between curvature and torsion is constant:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{\kappa}{\tau} = \frac{\frac{ \cos^2(\alpha)}{a}}{ \frac{\cos^3(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{a^2}} \\
                       \frac{\kappa}{\tau} = \frac{a}{\cos \left(\alpha\right)\sin \left(\alpha\right)} 
\end{equation}

Which is constant for any value of $a$ and $\alpha$, so I prove that the curve is a helix. But I need to demonstrate that **"the tangent vector $(T=r'(s))$ of the curve maintains a constant angle between it and a prescribed direction along the curve"**, which for me is sufficient by saying that the curve is a helix, but I want to demonstrate it mathematically.

Comment: Angle between $T$ and, say, the $x-y-$plane? A helix is $t\mapsto (\cos t,\sin t, t)\,.$ Its tangent vector is $(-\sin t,\cos t,1)\,.$ This vector has constant angle with the $x-y-$plane.

Comment: @KurtG, thanks for you reply, but i didn't understand you point, I think I miss something too. The fixed angle is between the Tangent vector and a prescribed direction over the curve. I edit my question

Comment: The tangent of any curve is -as far as I know- the direction of the curve. What is that *prescribed direction* ? Words words words.

Comment: Is the ***prescribed direction*** of the helix in my first comment the $z$-direction by any chance? If so, we have the answer. Angle stays constant with $xy$-plane, and obviously also with $z$-direction.